# Mocking base class protected property

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq, log4net

I am currently creating a `Mock` unit test for testing `LogManager` `Logger.Error()` call of class method as shown below.

```
public class Test : BaseClass
{
   public override void DoSomething(object value)
   {
      try
      { 
         if (value == null)
         {
             throw new Exception();
         }         
      }
      catch(exception ex)
      {
         Logger.Error("Exception raised!", ex);
      }
   }
}
```

My class uses a abstract base class which has a property defined as below for `ILog`

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   protected ILog Logger => LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
}
```

The issue is how do I go about mocking this base class property `Logger` so that I can test that `Logger.Error()` is raised?

Here is my unit test

```
[Test]
public void PassingNullParamShouldRaiseError()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockLog = new Mock<ILog>();
    var sut = new Test();

    // Action
    sut.DoSomething(null);

    // Assert
    mockLog.Verify(x => x.Error("Exception raised!"), Times.Once());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the base property *virtual*

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
   protected virtual ILog Logger => LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
}
```

You would now be able to override that property with a mock that can be used while testing

```
[Test]
public void PassingNullParamShouldRaiseError() {
    // Arrange
    var mockLog = new Mock<ILog>();

    var sut = new Mock<Test>() {
        CallBase = true //Important to be able to call base member
    };

    //override default behavior of protected logger
    sut.Protected()
        .Setup<ILog>("Logger")
        .Returns(mockLog.Object);

    // Act
    sut.Object.DoSomething(null);

    // Assert
    mockLog.Verify(x => x.Error("Exception raised!", It.IsAny<Exception>()), Times.Once());
}
```

Now ideally, your base class should not be tightly coupled to static implementation concerns like it is currently by using `LogManager`

The logger should be explicitly injected into the dependent class. Or at least via a log factory abstraction,

```
public interface ILoggerFactory {
    ILog GetLogger(Type type);
}
```

whose implementation can wrap that code smell

```
public class DefaultLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory {
    public ILog GetLogger(Type type) => LogManager.GetLogger(type);
}
```

That can be used to get the desired log

```
public class Test  {
    private readonly ILog logger;

    public Test(ILoggerFactory logs)  {
        logger = logs.GetLogger(GetType());
    }

    public void DoSomething(object value) {
        try {
            if (value == null) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.Error("Exception raised!", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very well explained and nice tip on not tightly coupling the base class.